# Search bar bug - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

In my app I have this kind of bug:

[image: ladida]

When I scroll down, the content of table is seen above the search bar. What can be the reason?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 52.0/255.0, green: 73.0/255.0, blue: 94.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @BSMP I've added the code of viewDidLoad, could you analyze  it, please?

Comment: @MartinR I've added the code of viewDidLoad, could you analyze  it, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should make the status bar not translucent.

The status bar's color is a [property of UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarStyle). You need to set it to a valid [UIStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIStatusBarStyle).

Comment: if I make it translucent, the search bar will disappear while typing

Comment: I've added the code of viewDidLoad, could you analyze  it, please?

Comment: Your `viewDidLoad` doesn't add anything. You should try to override preferredStatusBarStyle in your UIViewController as such: func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle { return UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque }` to tell the system that your controller want to display an opaque statusBar.

Answer (score 0):

The [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html) list 3 methods to prevent content from showing through the status bar.

> - Use a navigation controller to display content. A navigation controller automatically displays a status bar background and it
>     ensures that its content views don’t appear behind the status bar. (To
>     learn more about navigation controllers, see [Navigation Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2).)
> - Create a nondistracting custom image—such as a gradient—and display it behind the status bar. To ensure that the image stays
>     behind the status bar, you could use a view controller to keep the
>     image above a scrolling view or you could use a scrolling view to keep
>     it pinned to the top.
> - Position content to avoid the status bar area (that is, the area defined by the app’s [statusBarFrame](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarFrame) property). If you do this, you
>     should use the window’s background color to provide a solid color
>     behind the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

The new `UISearchController` has been designed to work with a `UITableView` and a `UINavigationBar`. Its functionality depends on your navigation bar being present. when the search bar has content in its text field, it will be latched on top of the page under the navigation bar. well, you don't have any navigation bar, it will latch to the top view guide and it always takes into account the status bar (if present) I guess the only way you can resolve your problem without an actual navigation bar is to add a view under status bar and make it opaque just like your search bar. it's a bit hacky but it's alright in my book.